# How to return errors in Laravel Custom Request to Ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request, laravel-response

I made custom request as following.

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
      $rule['name']='required';
      $rule['email'] = 'required|email';
      return $rule;
    }
}
```

How can I return validation errors in ajax?
When I didn't use custom request, I returned errors like this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'name'=>'required',
      'email'=>'required|email'
   ]
   if($validation->fails())
   {
      return response()->json([$errors=>$validation->errors()]);
   }
   return response()->json(['status'=>'success']);
}
```

So here instead of `Request`, if I use `CustomRequest` then how can we catch errors?

---

Another thing.
In custom request rule, how can we get request input values?

```
   public function rules()
    {
      $rule['name']='required';
      if($this->input('phone')) {
        $rule['phone'] = 'integer';
      }
      $rule['email'] = 'required|email';
      return $rule;
    }
```

$this->input('phone') Is this right? 
Hope to give me answer to my 2 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error will be either in your `error` call back function or `catch` callback depends on how you make `ajax` call.

eg.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "/test",
        type: "post",
        data: {foo:'test'} ,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;
            console.log(data.errors);// this will be the error bag.
        }
```

for `FormRequest` I think your code is not correct

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

This will do the validation. You do not really need to access the input value as Laravel does it for you. But for some reason, if you really want it you can always use the global helper function `request()->input('title');`

Comment: well, it returns 422 error (Unprocessable Entity) And I think Form validation rule is correct. Because it's same return values.($rule is array), With your simple return array, we can't validate according to input value.

Comment: it's 422, because something is wrong, there is no problem with it. you can still access the error message from it. @lovecoding

Comment: @lovecoding we can validate input, just `$validated = $request->validated();` this will give the validated input data.

Comment: @lovecoding the only thing is before it was `store(Request $request)` now it should be `store(CustomRequest $request)`

Comment: status [422](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422) is from rfc4918

Comment: Yes, You are right. I was catching errors in ajax success, but in this case, I think it will return message in ajax error.

Comment: Thanks,  It validated input values successfully but. how can we remove this error showing in browser? https://snipboard.io/LpGTSk.jpg

Comment: @lovecoding if it's in the `error` or `catch` it's treated as something is wrong, usually, code starts with 4**. So you cannot  remove it. just 404, 403 402. That's just how it is.

Comment: Well, but I think it's not good way, For validation, it shouldn't throw error in browser.

Comment: @lovecoding then fire an issue on `laravel` github ask to change the status code lol.

Comment: And also request()->input('title') this didn't work in rules() function. Instead of it, $this->title worked for me.

Comment: @lovecoding ah i did not know that, good point. but you do not need to get it manually anyways.